# Create a preview option for any kind of audio file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a website, where user can buy songs. But before purchasing them the user can preview the file as well (user can play only 20% of the song without paying or purchasing).
How can I implement that in wordpress using php???

Answer (score 0):

This plugin seems pretty good, and seems to offer most of what you're wanting:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/compact-wp-audio-player/

The snag is that you say you want to have a preview for "any kind of audio file".. I'm not sure you'll find any pre-built solution that will cover ALL file types, but if there's a small list that you'd need to cover we may be able to offer better solutions.